# Google is not pairing my 'div' tags correctly (ending it early)

Tags: php, html, foreach, tags, custom-wordpress-pages

I am coding a page for a custom WordPress theme and I am using PHP and Advanced Custom Fields to create the dynamic content for the page. All of my `div` tags have a start and an end to them but Google seems to be ending the `div` tag early by partnering it with the wrong end tag which is making my content look weird. Does anyone know why it is doing this and how to fix it?

I have already tried matching up all of my tags and I can't find one that isn't ended correctly so I'm at a loss as to what it could be.

Here is my code. I have tried to cut it down as much as I can but all of this is needed to see the Div pairing:

```
<div class="smaller-width center top">

    <div id="project-nav" class="title-section">
        <h1>Work.</h1>
        <nav id="project-filters">
        <button onClick="filterProj('All')" class="news-filter" ><p>All</p></button>
        <?php foreach($allCategories as $category) {
                        echo '<button onClick="filterProj('."'". $category->name ."'".')" class="news-filter" ><p>' .  $category->name . '</p></button>';
                } ?>

        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="projcont full center">
        <div class="news-inner">

        <div class="clr"></div>

            <div id="projects-section">
                <?php               
                    foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 

                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
                     $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
                ?>

                    <div class="project-post" data-categories="<?php 
                        foreach(wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'Project_Category', array("fields" => "all")) as $category) {
                            echo $category->name . ',';
                        } ?>">
                        <a class="single-project" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">                        
                            <div class="project-inside" style="background-image: url( <?php echo $image[0]; ?>);"> 
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                <?php the_title(); ?><br>
                                <span id="tag">
                                    <?php foreach(wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'Project_Category', array("fields" => "all")) as $category) {
                                        echo $category->name . ' ';
                                    } ?>
                                </span>
                                <i class="fas fa-angle-right project-arrow"></i>
                            </p>  
                        </a>

                <?php endif; ?>               

                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>     
        </div>
        <div id="load"> 
            <button href="#" id="loadMore">VIEW MORE</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Is there anything that sticks out here as to what might be breaking it?

Edit: Here is a screenshot of google ending my div early...
[image]
As you can see, the last 2 `project-post` id's should be inside the `project section`

Comment: I wonder from where is google coming in the picture. BTW where is your div tag closing?

Comment: Which `div` tag do you mean?

Comment: yes which/where?, "All of my div tags have a start and an end to them but Google seems to be ending the div tag"

Comment: Ah, it seems to be ending the `<div id="projects-section">` div early. I will add a screenshot from Google

Comment: Can you try formatting of all of  your <div class="project-post"> perhaps shift it on right. Formatting must be the issue. I dont think anyone can debug it from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting is your friend here. I have formatted your code in VS Code and I can see a little clearer what your issue is. The div you have between your ending if and for each statement is in the wrong place. I believe this is what is causing your issue.

```
<div class="smaller-width center top">
    <div id="project-nav" class="title-section">
        <h1>Work.</h1>
        <nav id="project-filters">
            <button onClick="filterProj('All')" class="news-filter" ><p>All</p></button>
            <?php foreach ($allCategories as $category) {
                echo '<button onClick="filterProj('."'". $category->name ."'".')" class="news-filter" ><p>' .  $category->name . '</p></button>';
            } ?>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="projcont full center">
        <div class="news-inner">
            <div class="clr"></div>
                <div id="projects-section">
                    <?php foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)):
                            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail');
                        ?>
                            <div class="project-post" 
                                data-categories="
                                    <?php
                                        foreach (wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'Project_Category', array("fields" => "all")) as $category) {
                                            echo $category->name . ',';
                                        } ?>">
                                <a class="single-project" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">                        
                                    <div class="project-inside" style="background-image: url( <?php echo $image[0]; ?>);"></div>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php the_title(); ?><br>
                                        <span id="tag">
                                            <?php foreach (wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'Project_Category', array("fields" => "all")) as $category) {
                                            echo $category->name . ' ';
                                        } ?>
                                        </span>
                                        <i class="fas fa-angle-right project-arrow"></i>
                                    </p>  
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>     
                    <?php endforeach; ?>          
                </div>
            </div>     
        </div>
        <div id="load"> 
            <button href="#" id="loadMore">VIEW MORE</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```